# How to properly get hasMany model in route

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have 2 models `Post` and `Comment`. Both have own routes: `PostRoute` and `PostCommentsRoute`, in the first case I simply use `@store.find` to load model data but I have a problem with the second route. When I try to refer to `Post` and then get its comments, they loads but don't update when I add new one. If I use `@store.find 'comment'`, it stays updated   however loads everything, so it's not the point. How to get only comments related to the post and keep them updated?

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend
  comments: DS.hasMany 'comment', async: true

App.Comment = DS.Model.extend
  post: DS.belongsTo 'post'

  text: DS.attr 'string'

App.Router.map ()->
  @resource 'post', path: '/post/:post_id', ()->
    @route 'comments'

App.PostCommentsController = Em.ArrayController.extend
  newComment: ""

  needs: 'post'
  post: Em.computed.alias 'controllers.post'
  sortProperties: ['created'],
  sortAscending: false

  actions:
    addComment: ()->
      commentText = @get 'newComment'
      post = @get 'post'
      comment = @store.createRecord 'comment',
        text: commentText
        post: post.get 'content'

      @set 'newComment', ''

      comment.save()

App.PostRoute = Em.Route.extend
  model: (params)->
    @store.find 'post', params.post_id

App.PostCommentsRoute = Em.Route.extend
  model: (params)->
    # loads only comments to parent post but doesn't update
    post = @modelFor 'post'
    post.get 'comments' # /api/posts/1/comments

App.PostCommentsRoute = Em.Route.extend
  model: (params)->
    # updates but loads all comments
    @store.find 'comment' # /api/comments
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you save your `comment` you have to push it on the `post`'s comments:

```
comment.save().then(function () {
  post.get('comments').push(comment);

  // or if that doesn't work you may need to resolve the promise:
  post.get('comments').then(function (comments) {
   comments.push(comment);
  });
});
```

Comment: To update comments list in PostCommentsRoute I had to change `comments` to `this.get('content')` but that's the solution.